# Copy Image From one SD to Another

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian. I want to put a new operating system on the SD but I also want to keep all my old config files and things for future reference and use. I do have another SD card but I don't want to use it. If possible, is there a way to copy the entire operating system onto the other SD and have it still bootable? Is there a way to do it from the RPi itself?

Comment: use the `dd` command of a unix system and clone the complete sd card to your harddrive. you can restore the sd card by `dd`ing back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SD Copy` in the GUI of the latest Raspbian to copy the card. This works even to different sized cards (obviously if big enough for the files).